# ASP.Net MVC Passing data from a view to a controller in a different folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, navigation

I am trying to send an Employee ID (1) from the EmployeeSelect.cfhtml view to the Workers_Compensation controller method "Create". I used the answers from this question: [Using Html.ActionLink to call action on different controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776781/using-html-actionlink-to-call-action-on-different-controller)

However, none of these answers work quite properly. When the Select button on the EmployeeSelect screen is pressed I need to navigate from https://localhost:44353/Employees/EmployeeSelect to https://localhost:44353/Workers_Compensation/Create/{ID} . But using the code from that question (and everywhere else I can find) what ends up happening is I navigate to https://localhost:44353/Employees/Create?Length=20 .

What am I doing wrong?

#### EmployeeSelect.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<HR_App_V1.Models.Employee>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee Select";
}

<h2>EmployeeSelect</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First_Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Last_Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.First_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Last_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Create", new { id = item.ID }) 
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

#### Workers_Compensation

```
 public ActionResult Create(int? id)
        {

            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Employee name: " + employee.First_Name);
            ViewBag.Claim_Ruling_TypeID = new SelectList(db.Claim_Ruling_Type, "ID", "Claim_Ruling_Type1");
            ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "ID", "ID");
            ViewBag.fName = new SelectList(db.Employees, "First_Name", "First_Name");
            ViewBag.lName = new SelectList(db.Employees, "Last_Name", "Last_Name");
            ViewBag.WC_TypeID = new SelectList(db.WC_Type, "ID", "WC_Type1");
            return View();
        }
```

If I manually navigate to https://localhost:44353/Workers_Compensation/Create/{ID} then everything works perfectly. But if I try to use the Select button it does not.

Comment: Can you show the whole view pls?

Comment: I edited the question to show the whole view.

Comment: And I am sorry but  i need your endpoints mappings from startup or webconfig, pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you changing a controller, you have to select htmlaction overload with 5 parameters. There is no a 4 input parameters htmlaction with a controller

Replace

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Create", new { id = item.ID })
```

with

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Create", "Workers_Compensation", new {id= item.ID }, null)
```

Comment: Oh wow, I see that most people used the null but I thought that was optional or something. Than you!